# ReCaptcha always returns false, with no error

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've installed the ReCaptcha, configured my public and private key, and everything is fine until I type any answer on it, no matter if it's good or wrong, it doesn't even respond with the error there was occurred.

Here is my code:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($config->privkey,   $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    echo $resp->error;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer after days of searching...

Here is the solution if someone is having a similar problem:

In your `rechaptchalib.php` change:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://api.recaptcha.net");
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net");
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname('api-verify.recaptcha.net'));
```

To the:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

It was probably caused by the outdated PHP library, so it'll be better for you to download the latest library also:

http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes. version 1.11 (for sure) has the new URLs.

Comment: Note that verification **recaptcha_check_answer(...)** is always done over **http** and never over **https**.  So your private key is sent in clear text, even if your public key is sent encrypted.  Odd choice on their part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have public key in your form file & private key in config file:

```
<html>
<body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
  <!-- your HTML content -->

  <form method="post" action="verify.php">
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  <!-- more of your HTML content -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is your file where form request goes:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

For further assistance you can go to: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html

Comment: Thats no matter if I have my public key in a config or form file... Your answer doesn't help , unfortunately.